# Remove the references of volume 2 in the volume 1 book and vice versa

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft, system-preferences, bibliography

I am writing a book and I had to split it into 2 volumes. How can I select the references that are only in volume 1 and those that are only in volume 2?

Comment: Try to divide the document into two sections. Each section then could have its own cross-reference.